# Truncate and reinser or insert unique

Tags: php, sql-server

My client gets CSV files or fixed width files which I need to insert into a database.
Each time they get a new file it contains all historical records in addition to the new ones.

My question is it better to truncate the whole table and reinsert them all or try to insert the unique rows only? If it is better to insert unique, how would this be done efficiently?

**Edit:** largest CSV is 186,868 rows with over 99% repeated data.

Comment: if you truncate the data, then reinsert the rows, will anyone notice?

Comment: No, one user accesses the data with crystal reports and will wait until it is done processing before accessing.

Comment: Depends on the total number of records, and average number of new/identical/deleted records...

Comment: @Alex-Info.net good point. if it's only a couple hundred then it would be quick, but a couple hundred thousand could become a performance problem

Comment: IMO, I'd insert all into a temp table, do a compare within db to find variances and move variances over.  If you always add the data again, what stops the provider from changing history... or do you care?  I'd then provide a report to my user base each import highlighting the differences.

Comment: If the old rows are never going to change and your only adding new rows to the csv, then you can check how many rows are in your database, and skip through the CSV until you reach that number

Comment: @SamuelCook hmm, that is an interesting approach. I'm not 100% sure if the data is sequential though or if it is mixed in.